# How to set some lines right aligned in the align enviroments?

Tags: align, multline

I have try some code like this:

```
\begin{align*}
Q(R)&=\bi(R,R)\\
    &=\bi(R_I+R_{\Rico}+R_W,R_I+R_{\Rico}+R_W)\\
    &=\bi(R_I,R_I)+2\bi(R_I,R_{\Rico})+2\bi(R_I,R_W)\\
    &+\bi(R_{\Rico},R_{\Rico})+2\bi(R_{\Rico},R_w)\\
    &+\bi(R_W,R_W).
\end{align*}
```

where

```
\newcommand{\Rico}{\Ric_o}
\newcommand{\bi}{\mathrm{bi}\,}
```

The problem is I would like to set the last three lines aligned right, did there has any solutions instead to type several \quad or \qquad?

Comment: maybe \hspace will be a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would place the last three equations in an extra `aligned` environment as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Ric}{Ric}
\newcommand{\Rico}{\Ric_o}
\DeclareMathOperator{\bi}{bi}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  Q(R) ={}&\bi(R,R)\\
  ={}&\bi(R_I+R_{\Rico}+R_W,R_I+R_{\Rico}+R_W)\\
  ={}&\begin{aligned}[t]
    \bi(R_I,R_I)+2\bi(R_I,R_{\Rico})+2\bi(R_I,R_W)&\\
    +\bi(R_{\Rico},R_{\Rico})+2\bi(R_{\Rico},R_w)&\\
    +\bi(R_W,R_W)&.
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Noticed the changed placement of the alignment charecter in relation to the equals signs and the consequent use of extra braces as `={}&` to ensure correct spacing.  I have also defined your missing commands with `\DeclareMathOperator`.  I chose to load `mathtools` instead of `amsmath`, but that is just personal preference; it loads `amsmath` anyway.

Comment: Personally, I would write `&=` as I write always. And then use `\!` before the `\begin{aligned}...`. Shorter in my opinion (may be not truly aligned, but it looks well).

Comment: @Manuel That is what I usually do too, but in this case the misalignment seemed too much.  I'll really have to understand one day what is going there.

Comment: I have just ignored the usage of [t] in my trying. By the way, I think {}& just give the right (balance) spacing of =, is it right?

Comment: @user19832 The `[t]` or `[b]` option is very useful for fixing the vertical alignment.  The documentation for the `mathtools` package uses `={}&` almost everywhere in alignments.  To my eyes (which often deceive me) it gives very tiny extra space in comparison with `&=`, but I haven't made any concrete measurements.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of options- you didn't tell us what the `\Ric` command is- please always post a complete `MWE` :)

[image: screenshot]

I would also use

```
\newcommand{\bi}{\operatorname{bi}}
```

for your `\bi` command, assuming I have interpreted it correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\Rico}{Ric_o}
%\newcommand{\bi}{\mathrm{bi}\,}
\newcommand{\bi}{\operatorname{bi}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
Q(R)&=\bi(R,R)\\
    &=\bi(R_I+R_{\Rico}+R_W,R_I+R_{\Rico}+R_W)\\
    &=\bi(R_I,R_I)+2\bi(R_I,R_{\Rico})+2\bi(R_I,R_W)\\
    &\phantom{{}=}+\bi(R_{\Rico},R_{\Rico})+2\bi(R_{\Rico},R_w)\\
    &\phantom{{}=}+\bi(R_W,R_W).
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
Q(R)&=\bi(R,R)\\
    &=\bi(R_I+R_{\Rico}+R_W,R_I+R_{\Rico}+R_W)\\
    &=\bi(R_I,R_I)+2\bi(R_I,R_{\Rico})+2\bi(R_I,R_W)\\
    &&&+\bi(R_{\Rico},R_{\Rico})+2\bi(R_{\Rico},R_w)\\
    &&&+\bi(R_W,R_W).
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```